# Loop through data validation list, copy and paste (variable number of cells) into another sheet, below each other

Tags: vba, excel, loops, macros, copy-paste

Hoping someone's able to kindly help me out with this!

I'm essentially trying to create a macro, which will loop through a list("A3") in one sheet("Dashboard"), and then copy the results (B3:B7) and paste into a second sheet ("PrintSheet", Column "A"), with all the results being pasted under each other.

So far, I've managed to come up with the following code, but for some reason, it only seems to copy and paste one row of results (B3, not B4,5,6 or 7).

Any help would be truly appreciated!

```
Sub SpitValues()
 Dim dvCell As Range
 Dim inputRange As Range
 Dim c As Range
 Dim i As Long

 'Cell that contains data validation list
 Set dvCell = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A3")

 'Determine where validation comes from
 Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

 i = 1

 'Begin loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In inputRange
     dvCell = c.Value

     Worksheets("PrintSheet").Cells(i, "A").Value = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B3:B7").Value
     i = i + 1

 Next c
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign the values from a multi-cell range to a single cell: both the source and destination must be the same size:

```
Worksheets("PrintSheet").Cells(i, "A").Resize(5, 1).Value = _
 Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B3:B7").Value
```